# Keep getting missing permission when trying to add to user only

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to allow read/write to only a users UID, however script keeps saying missing permission please help.

Many thanks`

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('details').add(...
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules you've written only match documents that are immediately within the collection called "users".  However, you're trying to access a document within a *subcollection* of a document of under "users".

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#hierarchical_data) addresses this situation very specifically, so be sure to read and understand how hierarchical data works for security rules.

If you want to apply per-user rules to *all* documents in a collection, and *all* the documents in *all* nested subcollections under that document, you can simply say this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      match /{document=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the match has to be nested like this in order it to use the `userId` wildcard from the outer match.

Comment: or simply in one line. you dont need to nested the matches since its the same check two time, just use one line: users/{userId}/details/{detail} . it may be not important here, but in checks that you access other documents, Firestore count each read as single, so you will have double reads count which will cost you more money.

Comment: @dAxx_ That one line wouldn't match documents existing in the users collection.  The nesting here is required, and they don't check twice.  There is no cost associated with these rules.  There is only cost if you use get() or exists() to check a document's contents.

Comment: it will work. you still can access the userId, look at how I have wrote it. and as I said, it may not be important here, but it might be important in other cases(I said it.)

Comment: @dAxx_ Feel free to write and test your rule and add it as an answer here. Be sure that it works for documents in users as well as users/{userid}/subcollection.

Comment: I dont need to test it, I know that its working, and I dont need to add answer since your answer is good enough. I was just adding a Side note as consideration when the rules are a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your forgot to enable sign-in provider in the firebase console.[image]